# Finding ΔH and ΔS given Gibbs free energy at two temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

Question: Gibbs free energy of a reaction at $\ce{300 K}$ and $\pu{310 K}$ are $\pu{-28 kcal}$ and $\pu{–28.5 kcal}$   respectively. Determine $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ at $\pu{300 K}$.

---

I tried forming equations using the given data. If I assume the enthalpy to be a constant irrespective of temperature, I will get a system of two simultaneous equations in $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ which can be solved. Using: (1) $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$, and (2) replacing $\Delta G$ for the mentioned values, I obtain
\begin{align}
  \pu{-28 kcal}   &= \Delta H - (\pu{300 K}) \Delta S \tag{1} \\
  \pu{-28.5 kcal} &= \Delta H - (\pu{310 K}) \Delta S \tag{2}
\end{align}

However, I think this approach is incorrect. Enthalpy is a temperature dependant quantity and $\Delta H$ at $\pu{300 K}$ won't be equal to $\Delta H$ at $\pu{310 K}$.

I think the question lacks sufficient data to be solved.

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: You overcomplicate it.  You are right that ΔH but even ΔS are temperature dependent, based on the difference of heat capacity of reagents and products. But that simple exercise neglects it for simplicity. Give them what they expect with a relevant note.

Comment: Note that various equations like the van't Hoff one or Clausius-Clapeiron(?) one imply constant ΔH, assuming they will not be used over wide T range.

Comment: The parameters ΔH and ΔS have units, and the numerical values have uncertainties. Which ones ? If the two values of ΔG are known to ± 0.1 unit(?) and if the temperatures are known to ± 0.1 K,  it means that the calculated value of ΔS is known with an uncertainty of at least ± 60%. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Maurice You are true. But I guess you go behind the expected complexity level of the task. I think they do not expect statistical evaluation.

Comment: Over such a small temperature range it is safe to assume changes in H and S are nil . Thus you have two equations and two unknowns.